# Connection error between AWS Glue and Redshift

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-redshift, aws-glue, amazon-vpc, aws-glue-connection

I have my csv in S3 which I want to move into a redshift cluster through AWS Glue, but every time I test the connection between Glue and Redshift I get the following error:

```
"InvalidInputException: VPC S3 endpoint validation failed for SubnetId: subnet-0ec2f5b729f868155. VPC: vpc-0a3d73ac9fd20182f. Reason: Could not find S3 endpoint or NAT gateway for subnetId: subnet-0ec2f5b729f868155 in Vpc vpc-0a3d73ac9fd20182f"
```

Can someone help me with a list of detailed steps of what i need to do?

I have tried reading the documentation but haven't been able to figure it out. I understand the issue is somewhere in the permissions of the IAM role or the some security permissions.

I tried tweaking the security permissions, but did not find a solution.

Comment: Have you created an S3 Endpoint in your VPC?  This is the simplest way to gain access to S3 from an otherwise disconnected VPC.

Comment: https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/glue-s3-endpoint-validation-failed

Comment: Turn on advanced vpc routing for your cluster